# Directory.GetFiles() throws UnauthorizedAccessException on system directory with localized name

Tags: c#, windows, file, localization

I was trying to iterate over start menu items on a zh-CN Windows 10 PC, but failed like the title said.

The problematic code:

```
public static readonly string[] ItemSearchPath = new[]
{
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu)
};

public static readonly string[] ItemSearchPattern = new[] {@"*.lnk", @"*.url"};

// ...

foreach (var item in ItemSearchPath.SelectMany(x => ItemSearchPattern.SelectMany(y =>
    Directory.GetFiles(x, y, SearchOption.AllDirectories))) /* <- here */ { ... }
```

Stacktrace:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\程序' is denied.
```

At first I thought this was due to file permissions, so I elevated Visual Studio and forced the program to use admin priviledges in `app.manifest`, but the exception was still thrown. Soon I realized the path actually points to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`.

The "run" dialog rejects the localized path as well, so it was a expected behavior at the level of opening a directory. But from what Google told me the localized name is nothing but a key in `desktop.ini`, so getting it instead of the "real" one inside a standard method is odd. Am I just using the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

There's always the chance, when parsing System Paths, to face a denial trying to access a Directory/File without the required Access rights.

You, however, can check if those rights are granted to the current user, before attemping any operation on that Directory/File.

Here I'm using [WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfs49sw0(v=vs.110).aspx) to retrieve the User ACL Identity, then, using [Directory.GetAccessControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1f66bc2(v=vs.110).aspx), verify if the User rights meet the [AuthorizationRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.authorizationrule(v=vs.110).aspx) required to, at least, access that Path.

I've added a method, `UserHasDirectoryAccesRight(string DirPath) { }` that performs the test.

> Note that this is a generic method, it must be tuned to a specific
>   Culture. I've added a string conversion, using
>   `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, on the Directory Paths to try to fit in.
>   Modify this setting as required.

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.AccessControl;

string[] ItemSearchPath = new[] {
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartMenu),
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu)
};

string[] itemSearchPattern = new[] { @"*.lnk", @"*.url" };

List<string> linksList = itemSearchPath.SelectMany(sPath =>
                         itemSearchPattern.SelectMany(sPatt =>
                         {
                             return UserHasDirectoryAccesRight(sPath)
                                    ? Directory.GetFiles(
                                                sPath.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                                sPatt.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture),
                                                            SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                    : new string[] { "" };
                         })).ToList();

private bool UserHasDirectoryAccesRight(string DirPath)
{
    WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(false);
    AuthorizationRuleCollection dSecurity =
            Directory.GetAccessControl(DirPath, AccessControlSections.Access)
                     .GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

    bool hasRight =  dSecurity.Cast<AuthorizationRule>()
                              .Any(x => x.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(identity.Owner.Value));
    return hasRight;
}
```

Comment: All I get is 'Directory' does not contain a definition for 'GetAccessControl' when trying this.That is System.IO.Directory.

Comment: [Directory.GetAccessControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol). Not available in .Net Core. I made a couple of changes and tested it.